# OpenCv Compiling with Cuda

Tags: opencv, cuda, cmake

I'm giving this command

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/developments/opencv/install/opencv/* -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/  ..

but always cmake gives me

--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Clp:                     NO

How can it be done?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your full CMake report? What CUDA version do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you don't have the required CUDA version installed. The output of cmake should be warning you about it.

OpenCV 2.3.1 supports only CUDA 4.0.

OpenCV 2.4 supports CUDA 4.1 and 4.2.

Comment: btw ive solved problem.Problem is cmake version.ubuntu has 2.8.0 and i compiled 2.8.7 and all of them are ok.Thanks for aswers