# Error in building OpenCV 2.4xx with Cuda 10.2

Tags: opencv, cuda

I am trying to build OpenCV 2.4 with Cuda-10.2 which is installed on Jetson AGX Xavier. I have followed [this](https://davidstutz.de/compiling-opencv-2-4-x-with-cuda-9/) blog post in order to change the files so that opencv is able to find all cuda libraries.

I am running the following command to generate cmake cache:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/lib/opencv_2.4/installed -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DCUDA_GENERATION=Volta -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5 -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-8 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-8 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-8 ..
```

I am getting the following error when I do make or make -j8

```
[ 56%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_photo
[ 56%] Built target opencv_perf_photo
[ 56%] Built target opencv_gpu_pch_dephelp
[ 57%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_gpu
[ 58%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_bf_knnmatch.cu.o
In file included from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/functional.hpp:50:0,
                 from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/vec_distance.hpp:47,
                 from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu:49:
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/include/device_functions.h:54:2: warning: #warning "device_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead." [-Wcpp]
 #warning "device_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead."
  ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/functional.hpp:50:0,
                 from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/vec_distance.hpp:47,
                 from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu:49:
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/include/device_functions.h:54:2: warning: #warning "device_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead." [-Wcpp]
 #warning "device_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead."
  ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/functional.hpp:50:0,
                 from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/vec_distance.hpp:47,
                 from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu:49:
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/include/device_functions.h:54:2: warning: #warning "device_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead." [-Wcpp]
 #warning "device_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead."
  ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/functional.hpp:50:0,
                 from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/vec_distance.hpp:47,
                 from /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu:49:
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/include/device_functions.h:54:2: warning: #warning "device_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead." [-Wcpp]
 #warning "device_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead."
  ^~~~~~~
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/../warp_shuffle.hpp(60): error: identifier "__shfl" is undefined

/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/../warp_shuffle.hpp(71): error: identifier "__shfl" is undefined

/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/../warp_shuffle.hpp(92): error: identifier "__shfl_down" is undefined

/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/../warp_shuffle.hpp(103): error: identifier "__shfl_down" is undefined

/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/../warp_shuffle.hpp(124): error: identifier "__shfl_up" is undefined

/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/../warp_shuffle.hpp(135): error: identifier "__shfl_up" is undefined

/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/../warp_shuffle.hpp(84): error: identifier "__shfl_down" is undefined
          detected during:
            instantiation of "T cv::gpu::device::shfl_down(T, unsigned int, int) [with T=float]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(75): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::findBestMatch<BLOCK_SIZE>(float &, float &, int &, int &, float *, int *) [with BLOCK_SIZE=16]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(401): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::matchUnrolledCached<BLOCK_SIZE,MAX_DESC_LEN,Dist,T,Mask>(cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T>, cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T>, Mask, int2 *, float2 *) [with BLOCK_SIZE=16, MAX_DESC_LEN=64, Dist=cv::gpu::device::L1Dist<cv::gpu::device::uchar>, T=unsigned char, Mask=cv::gpu::device::SingleMask]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(420): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::matchUnrolledCached<BLOCK_SIZE,MAX_DESC_LEN,Dist,T,Mask>(const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const Mask &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<int2> &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<float2> &, cudaStream_t) [with BLOCK_SIZE=16, MAX_DESC_LEN=64, Dist=cv::gpu::device::L1Dist<cv::gpu::device::uchar>, T=unsigned char, Mask=cv::gpu::device::SingleMask]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(852): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::match2Dispatcher<Dist,T,Mask>(const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const Mask &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, cudaStream_t) [with Dist=cv::gpu::device::L1Dist<cv::gpu::device::uchar>, T=unsigned char, Mask=cv::gpu::device::SingleMask]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(1149): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::matchDispatcher<Dist,T,Mask>(const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, int, const Mask &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzf &, cudaStream_t) [with Dist=cv::gpu::device::L1Dist<cv::gpu::device::uchar>, T=unsigned char, Mask=cv::gpu::device::SingleMask]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(1166): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::matchL1_gpu<T>(const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, int, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzf &, cudaStream_t) [with T=cv::gpu::device::uchar]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(1172): here

/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/../warp_shuffle.hpp(84): error: identifier "__shfl_down" is undefined
          detected during:
            instantiation of "T cv::gpu::device::shfl_down(T, unsigned int, int) [with T=int]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(77): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::findBestMatch<BLOCK_SIZE>(float &, float &, int &, int &, float *, int *) [with BLOCK_SIZE=16]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(401): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::matchUnrolledCached<BLOCK_SIZE,MAX_DESC_LEN,Dist,T,Mask>(cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T>, cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T>, Mask, int2 *, float2 *) [with BLOCK_SIZE=16, MAX_DESC_LEN=64, Dist=cv::gpu::device::L1Dist<cv::gpu::device::uchar>, T=unsigned char, Mask=cv::gpu::device::SingleMask]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(420): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::matchUnrolledCached<BLOCK_SIZE,MAX_DESC_LEN,Dist,T,Mask>(const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const Mask &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<int2> &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<float2> &, cudaStream_t) [with BLOCK_SIZE=16, MAX_DESC_LEN=64, Dist=cv::gpu::device::L1Dist<cv::gpu::device::uchar>, T=unsigned char, Mask=cv::gpu::device::SingleMask]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(852): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::match2Dispatcher<Dist,T,Mask>(const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const Mask &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, cudaStream_t) [with Dist=cv::gpu::device::L1Dist<cv::gpu::device::uchar>, T=unsigned char, Mask=cv::gpu::device::SingleMask]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(1149): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::matchDispatcher<Dist,T,Mask>(const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<T> &, int, const Mask &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzf &, cudaStream_t) [with Dist=cv::gpu::device::L1Dist<cv::gpu::device::uchar>, T=unsigned char, Mask=cv::gpu::device::SingleMask]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(1166): here
            instantiation of "void cv::gpu::device::bf_knnmatch::matchL1_gpu<T>(const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, int, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzb &, const cv::gpu::PtrStepSzf &, cudaStream_t) [with T=cv::gpu::device::uchar]" 
/home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/modules/gpu/src/cuda/bf_knnmatch.cu(1172): here

8 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000021a9_00000000-7_bf_knnmatch.compute_72.cpp1.ii".
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_bf_knnmatch.cu.o.cmake:264 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/nvidia/opencv-2.4/build/modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_bf_knnmatch.cu.o


modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_gpu.dir/build.make:503: recipe for target 'modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_bf_knnmatch.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_bf_knnmatch.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4741: recipe for target 'modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_gpu.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_gpu.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have also tried it with -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.2. I get the same error.
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The version of OpenCV you are trying to build doesn't support the version of the CUDA toolkit you have. You either need to use an older version of the CUDA toolkit or a newer version of the OpenCV source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV 2.4 will not work with CUDA Toolkit 10.2.  It was originally designed for both versions 4.1 and 4.2.  You might be able to get that code to compile and run if you can downgrade to CUDA 9. Otherwise you would have to rewrite those kernels to remove usage of deprecated instructions which are no longer supported and can't work on your Volta GPU.

Reference: [OpenCv Compiling with Cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608762/opencv-compiling-with-cuda?rq=1)

Comment: Note that he is working on very new Jetson ARM embedded system. CUDA 4 (or anything before about CUDA 9) won't work on his system

Comment: @talonmies thanks for the note. Upon further research OpenCV 2.4 can work with CUDA 9 with some hacking. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @talonmies!